# macOSでのIntelliJでのgit操作

Tags: macos, git, intellij-idea

macOSでIntelliJでgithubからcloneしようとするとsudo xcodebuild -licenseコマンドを叩くようにとエラーが出ます
そこでコマンドを叩きスペースで最後まで読みagreeと入力しているのですがgit連携をしようとすると同じコマンドを叩けとエラーが出てしまいます
ターミナルなどでは目的のものをcloneできるのですが何かintellJで設定が必要なのでしょうか
ご存知の方がいたら教えてください
よろしくお願いします

#### 追記

git のバージョンは以下の通りです

```sh
$ git --version
git version 2.17.2 (Apple Git-113)
```

表示されているメッセージは以下の通りです

```
Accept XCode/iOS License to Run Git: Run “sudo xcodebuild -license” and retry (admin rights required)
```

2019/3/25追記
intelliJを再起動したらうまく行きました
ご迷惑おかけしました

Comment: `git --version` の出力結果を追記して頂けませんでしょうか？

Comment: ```$ git --version
git version 2.17.2 (Apple Git-113)```です

Comment: > sudo xcodebuild -licenseコマンドを叩くようにとエラーが出ます これは「よくある問題の解決策」として表示されている気がします。意訳ではなく表示されているメッセージ原文を省略せずに転記するようにしてください。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます`Accept XCode/iOS License to Run Git: Run “sudo xcodebuild -license” and retry (admin rights required)
`と表示されています

Comment: @Nickname さん、解決して良かったです（お役に立てなくてすいません）。ところで、スタック・オーバーフローでは問題が自己解決した場合に[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)を推奨しています。回答後しばらくすると自分の回答を承認することもできるようになりますので、是非お願いいたします :)

Comment: @nekketsuuu  指摘ありがとうございます。自己回答しました

Answer (score 1):

intelliJを再起動したらうまく行きました
ご迷惑おかけしました